# Flutter (Web) - Using Routes with Navigation Rail

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-web

Is it possible to push a name in the url (flutter web) without loading the widget?

like :

```dart
return MaterialApp(
      title: 'mytitle',
      initialRoute: '/home',
      routes: {
        '/home': (context) => SafeArea(child: NavigationRailBar(initialIndex: 0)),
        '/item1': // don't do anything but bind a destination with a url on click of the navigationrail
        '/item2' : //
        '/item3': //
      
      },
```

Because NavigationRail already send you to the right "destination"